# Embed Winstone with jetty server

Tags: java, rest, jetty, embedded-jetty, winstone

I have a jar file embedded with jetty and a war file running on winstone. I need to embed two projects with same server or is it possible to embed winstone with jetty server to run on same port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't combine those on the same port.

However, you can do something else ...

1. Migrate your winstone use to the [embedded-jetty-live-war](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-live-war) pattern
2. Merge your [embedded-jetty](/questions/tagged/embedded-jetty) jar file code into the [`theserver/src/main/java/jetty/livewar/ServerMain.java`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-live-war/blob/master/theserver/src/main/java/jetty/livewar/ServerMain.java) from the `embedded-jetty-live-war` example project (maintained by the Jetty Project)

The end result is a single Server instance, with 2 webapps running in it.

You can choose to have it exist as a live-war (aka winstone like), or as a Jar executable that just loads the `WebAppContext` of the war file as a second handler on the Server. (use a `HandlerCollection` or `HandlerList` with the `Server.setHandler()` call)